# Stylelint - Ensure class name prefix matches folder name

Tags: css, stylelint

I am using the "[selector-class-pattern](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/selector-class-pattern/)" stylelint rule. The pattern I am using is to enforce the [ECSS](http://ecss.io/) naming standard. The rule looks like this:

```
"selector-class-pattern": ["^[a-z]([a-z0-9]){1,3}-[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+(_[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(-([a-z0-9-]+)?[a-z0-9])?$", { "resolveNestedSelectors": true }]
```

An ECSS class name uses 3 parts (module name, component name, element name) and looks something like `.mod-Component_Element {}` where `mod` is an abbreviation of the module name.

My SCSS files are kept in component folders, so the folder structure looks like the below, where `app` is the name of the module.

```
app
-- component-name
  -- component-name.component.js
  -- component-name.component.scss
```

I would like a stylelint rule to ensure that the module and the component part of class names match the folder they are in. So the class names kept in the example **component-name.component.scss** file would be restricted to `.app-ComponentName_ElementName {}` where `ElementName` is optional and can be anything.

I am using Gulp to run stylelint:

```
gulp.task('css', () => {
  let processors = [
    // add postcss processors here
  ];
  return gulp.src([
    path.join(gconfig.rootDir, 'vars.style.scss'),
    path.join(gconfig.rootDir, 'style.scss'),
    path.join(gconfig.rootDir, gconfig.rootModule, '**/*.scss'),
  ])
    .pipe(stylelint({
      failAfterError: false,
      reporters: [ {formatter: 'string', console: true} ]
    }))
    .pipe(gif( debug, sourcemaps.init() ))
    .pipe(cssimport())
    .pipe(concat(`${gconfig.projectName}.style.css`))
    .pipe(scss().on('error', scss.logError))
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gif( debug, sourcemaps.write() ))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(gconfig.outDir, 'css')))
});
```

I understand I will probably need to write a plugin for this, but wondered if there is already a plugin for something like this out there, or if there are any ways to do it maybe by passing the file name/folder to stylelint from Gulp?

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen anything that does what you're asking *out of the box*

The closest similar plugins I've seen would be the BEM plugins:

- https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter
- https://github.com/davidtheclark/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern

These might work as a base guide on writing some plugins for your ECSS use case